# DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy constructor from Apache Httpclient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

The class [DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy.html#DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy%28int,%20int%29) from Apache Httpclient v.4 has a constructor that accepts two parameters. The first, `int maxRetries`, is clear; the second `int retryInterval` has a clear scope, but I don't undestand if it must represent minutes, seconds or something else. The doc doesn't specify this particular.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, *sometimes* the docs are not well documented. Anyway, I have the source code here. I just copy and paste the field declaration inside the
`DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy` class:

```
/**
 * Retry interval between subsequent requests, in milliseconds. Default
 * value is 1 second.
 */
private final long retryInterval;
```

as you may see it is **milliseconds**, while default value is 1000 (i.e. 1 second).

Also I believe that *milliseconds* is a standard for times! But I'm not pretty sure about this!